# Expresiones regulares, números después del guion bajo "_"

Tags: javascript, regex

estoy tratando de separar 34_567 en dos números en javascript,num1 = 34 y num2 = 567 con expresiones regulares, tengo el num1 con esta expresión [^*]* pero no he podido obtener el num2 es decir lo que esta después del guion bajo "*".

¿Que expresión puedo usar para tener el numero después del "_"?

Comment: En que software?

Comment: para javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder separarlo, podrías hacer uso del método `split()`. Lo que hace este método es **crear un array** en base al **separador** que se le especifique; es decir, para este caso, nos creará un `array` el cual sus elementos serían `34` y `567`.

El código sería el siguiente:

```
    let my_cadena = "34_567";
    let items_separados = my_cadena.trim().split('_');

    console.log(items_separados[0]); // Imprime el N° 34
    console.log(items_separados[1]); // Imprime el N° 567
```

PD: El método `trim()` elimina los espacios que hay a los costados de nuestra cadena.

Comment: Gracias Moisés Huamán C. funciono a la perfección. cambie los console.log por un alert para que me los mostrara en la misma pagina en las que estoy trabajando y si me mostro los numeros separados

Comment: De nada @xMuguix, saludos :D.